# Why does `intRange.endInclusive` produce a warning?

Tags: kotlin

The following code produces the lint warning "Could be replaced with unboxed `last`":

```kotlin
fun foo() {
    val range = 1..3
    range.endInclusive
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Replacing `endInclusive` with `last` clears the warning.

But why?  What is wrong with this code?  I would have expected `endInclusive` to be the correct property to use for an IntRange.

(I'm using Kotlin 1.3.70 in Android Studio 3.6.1.)

Comment: The same applies to `intRange.start`. That produces the lint warning "Could be replaced with unboxed `first`".

Comment: Although it was asked here first, a better answer can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61092285/in-kotlin-whats-the-difference-between-start-and-first.

Comment: Hmm, I find this answer clearer, in large part due to the inclusion of `IntProgression` in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class `IntRange` inherits class `IntProgression` and implements interface `ClosedRange<Int>`.

`last` is a property of class `IntProgression`. This class is not generic, property's type is `Int` and it does not have custom getter/setter. `last` is translated into a method `getLast()` that returns a value of unboxed type `int`.

`endInclusive` is an abstract property of interface `ClosedRange<Int>`. This interface is generic, property's type is defined as `T` and, moreover, its implementation in class `IntRange` has a custom getter (which just returns `last`). `endInclusive` is translated into a method `getEndInclusive()` that returns a value of boxed type `Integer`.

Comment: Hi. The last part doesn't appear to be correct, as `endInclusive` is a property of IntRange, of type Int: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/-int-range/end-inclusive.html

Comment: It's not that simple. `endInclusive` in `IntRange` overrides `endInclusive` abstract property of `ClosedRange<Int>`: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/-closed-range/end-inclusive.html#endinclusive

Comment: In source code, `endInclusive` in `IntRange` is declared as `override val endInclusive: Int get() = last`

Comment: And if you call `range.getLast()` and `range.getEndInclusive()` from Java code, any IDE will show you the difference in types.

Comment: I see. But why is there a warning at all here? If I look at the generated bytecode for `range.endInclusive`, I see that it simply calls IntRange.getEndInclusive. There is no problem here or boxing involved.

Comment: Are we supposed to just not use `start` or `endInclusive`? If so, why does IntRange even define them?

Comment: Look at the type of `range.getEndInclusive()` and `range.getLast()`. The first one returns `Integer` while the second one returns `int`. IntelliJ IDEA clearly shows it when you write the method call.

Comment: Yes, we are supposed to use `last` instead of `endInclusive` everywhere. `IntRange` does NOT define `endInclusive` and `startInclusive`, it just implements `ClosedRange<Int>` where these properties are defined as abstract, so `IntRange` has to implement them. There is no way to implement `ClosedRange<Int>` without these properties.

Comment: Note that `endInclusive` does **not** return a "boxed `Integer`": both `last` and `endInclusive` return an unboxed Kotlin `Int`. What is boxed or unboxed is the `IntRange` object itself on which this is called: because `last` is a property of the non-generic class `IntProgression` (the base class of `IntRange`) invoking it on an instance does not require it to be boxed, as opposed to `endInclusive` which is a property of the generic interface `ClosedRange<>` (in this case `ClosedRange<Int>`), and so when invoked on an `IntRange` instance it must first be boxed and cast to the interface.