# In Kotlin, what's the difference between start and first?

Tags: kotlin, range

I'm learning Kotlin, but I can't seem to find straight answers to simple questions.  I presume that it's so new, no one has had a chance to ask the obvious questions yet.  So here it goes.

When I want to get the smallest item in a range, I type:

```
range.start
```

But I get the warning, "Could be replaced with unboxed `first`".  Not sure what *unboxed* means--can't even guess.  But when I use this command:

```
range.first
```

the warning goes away.  What's happening here?  Should I even be concerned?  Why does Kotlin have both a *start* and a *first*?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Boxing and unboxing refers to wrapping a primitive value in a class so it can be used with generic classes and functions or as a nullable. In Java, this is more transparent because the primitive and boxed versions of each type of variable have different names (i.e. `int` and `Integer`), whereas in Kotlin this is not very obvious. If your variable is nullable, like `Int?`, it is always boxed, but if it's non-nullable, it's only boxed if it's passed to a function that's generic or requests a nullable version. So *boxing* as a verb refers to the variable getting wrapped in a class at the moment it is passed to something that requires a boxed version.

There is an interface for a generic range called `ClosedRange`. When you are working with integer ranges, you are using a class called `IntRange` that also implements `ClosedRange<Int>`.

When you use the properties of the generic interface like `start`, the JVM has to box and unbox your `Int` value. This is because generics cannot be used with non-boxed primitives. There is a small amount of runtime overhead to box and unbox the primitive.

The actual class `IntRange` stores the values for the start and end of the range as primitives, so if you access them directly with `first`, you bypass the boxing that occurs if you go through the generic interface property, for a small performance gain.

In the vast majority of cases, the performance difference will be negligible anyway, but the default code inspection recommends you to use the more performant way.

Comment: That's a whole lot of explanation for what amounts to a whole lot of work to get what should be just a constant.  Glad we switched to kotlin--it's soooo much more intuitive!

Comment: The short answer is just don’t worry about it unless you’re trying to highly optimize some piece of code. It’s an unfortunate result of the way Java handles generics.